Seven segment display special characters/symbols

How can one add these symbols in seven segment displays? I would like to add some symbols of pwr,ch1,ch2,ch3 to my product. Does anyone know what this is called and who can do manufacturing of this?

For characters, alphanumeric display is more suitable.

You have to find a manufacturer that can build a custom display

They are just individual LEDs that shine through the front panel mask with text printed on the mask.
It really has nothing to do with 7-segment displays that are below these individual LEDs.

They are probably custom displays made in a similar way to the 7-segment display modules and bar graph modules. Whenever I meet with the folks who manufacture those LED displays they typically have on display a large number of custom displays for dashboard displays, toys, air conditioners and  so. Autonics is a large company and does not need to limit themselves to what is in the catalog of LED makers.
The numbers themselves are likely printed in reverse on the plastic panel, probably of the order of 0.25mm thick and in intimate contact with the display surfaces. The LED display provides the backlighting.
You could get a similar effect by purchasing individual LEDs, either with shrouds molded on (4x6mm with an outer white 'skin' is common) or providing your own shroud by high-resolution 3D printing. Unfortunately, high-resolution 3D printing tends to not produce opaque parts (because it's typically done with SLA, which uses light to polymerize the resin) but perhaps there are other processes.
Individual LEDs lacking the shrouds behind a printed graphic panel and mounted that closely will tend to bleed badly from one to the next one(s) so I think it's more than that.
Anyway, if you want to look for a company that makes such things, I would suggest searching for "LED bar graph module" and sifting through catalogs since many companies make 10-segement bar graph modules.
Alternatively, look at using a color (eg. LCD) graphic display and rendering whatever images you like, however that has profound consequences in an instrument design such as this one.
